# Javafx Scene.snapshot method with slow performance

Tags: java, performance, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am making a sliding animation to switch a scene to another scene, but when I call this method, it has a delay for switching scene. I found that the cause is a method `snapshot()` of class `Scene`. 
Does anyone have a solution?

code:

```
public void switchScene(Scene target) {
    Scene current = getPrimaryStage().getScene();
    WritableImage beforeImage;
    WritableImage afterImage;

    int width = ((int) ((Region) current.getRoot()).getWidth());
    int height = ((int) ((Region) current.getRoot()).getHeight());

    beforeImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
    ImageView leftImage = new ImageView(current.snapshot(beforeImage));

    afterImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
    ImageView rightImage = new ImageView(target.snapshot(afterImage));

    leftImage.setTranslateX(0);
    rightImage.setTranslateX(width);

    StackPane animation = new StackPane(leftImage, rightImage);
    animation.setPrefSize(target.getWidth(), target.getHeight());

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(animation));

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(rightImage.translateXProperty(), 0, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.75), kv);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.setOnFinished(t -> {
        // remove pane and restore scene 1
        primaryStage.setScene(target);
    });
    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do up there. But, why don't you make an asynchronous call to the [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#snapshot(javafx.util.Callback,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) method?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a snapshot in this way is an inherently slow operation, there's not a great deal that can be done to speed it up while staying in Java land. As suggested in the comment, if you really want to take a snapshot then a better approach would be to use the asynchronous method, which won't block the UI thread while it runs (so while they'll still be a delay, your app will still remain responsive.)

However, if I've understood your example correctly, there's absolutely no need to use screenshots at all - why are you using images rather than just animating the nodes themselves? Remember that all JavaFX elements are nodes of the scenegraph, so can be animated in the same way. So instead of:

```
StackPane animation = new StackPane(leftImage, rightImage);
```

You should just be able to do:

```
StackPane animation = new StackPane(source, target);
```

...then use this to animate the panes directly without going through the slow process of taking screenshots.